# Can I change 50 amp circuit breaker out for a 20 amp?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I need to change a 50 amp breaker out for a 20 amp breaker, can I do that without changing the 6AWG wire?

Comment: Reading between the lines here, it's possible that this question is asking how to put a NEMA 5 plug for a new gas range into a 50-amp receptacle for an existing electric range. In these cases, there are [adapters](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-Gas-Range-Adapter-9042SW8801/302183109) which are safe and code-compliant _as long as_ the existing circuit is grounded and the adapter contains a fuse to protect the 20-amp appliance.

Answer (score 23):

If the breaker can handle the wire directly, great. If not then you need to pigtail the 6 AWG wire to a smaller wire, but at least 12 AWG.

So to the specifications we go:

- Square D QO - maximum 8 AWG. [Square D web site - see Datasheet](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/QO120/mini-circuit-breaker-qo-20a-1-pole-120-240vac-10ka-plug-in-mount/)
- Square D HOM - maximum 8 AWG [Square D web site - see Datasheet](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOM120/mini-circuit-breaker-homeline-20a-1-pole-120-240vac-10ka-air-standard-type-plug-in-ul/)
- Eaton BR - maximum 4 AWG [Eaton web site](https://www.eaton.com/mx/en-us/skuPage.BR120.html)
- Eaton CH - maximum 8 AWG [Eaton web site](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.CH120.specifications.html)
- GE Q-line - maximum 8 AWG (various internet sources)

So it looks like Eaton BR is the outlier. For anything else you'll need a pigtail.

Depending on what you are putting on the other end, you may need a pigtail there as well. Do **not** simply "make it fit" - that can lead to a high resistance connection which can cause a fire.

It looks like an Ideal 342 Gray, 454 Blue, WT54 Blue and some other wire nuts will work to pigtail 12 AWG to 6 AWG. Again, check the specifications carefully.

Comment: OP will also have to pigtail the other end, most likely. :)

Comment: And when using wire connectors to join wires this far apart in size, be really sure they are solidly connected. It's easy to end up with the connector just threaded on to the end of the big wire. I'm a fan of using splice kits for this sort of pigtail, but that's mostly because I hate wire nuts and don't mind the cost increase.

Answer (score 11):

Using 6AWG wire on a 20A circuit is perfectly fine, but it may not be allowed directly on the 20A breaker's terminals. For example, in the Square-D QO line, the QO120 and QO220 breakers allow 14AWG-8AWG wires. They do not allow 6AWG. You'd have to attach a short pigtail of 12AWG-8AWG to the breaker, and then splice that to the 6AWG. Check the datasheet of the breaker you're planning to use.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Your wires can handle 20A, so it is good. You can always use thicker than needed.

Comment: Short, simple,and misses the important bit about not trying to shove a #6 wire into a breaker (or device at the other end) that cannot accepts a #6 wire. No -1 from me, but no +1, either.